# Bash script I need to rename files in bash so first part of filename is moved ot last part of filename

Tags: linux, bash, script, rename

So here is one of the filenames as an example.

`2017-11-09-23.00.19-CookingDoughnuts.txt`

Rename to

`CookingDoughnuts-2017-11-09-23.00.19.txt`

I need to do this en masse to 1000s of files so it is a script, the part of the script I am stuck with is the actual rename bit.  But a complete script can be supplied if it makes it easier to post a solution.

I can say the dated format is the same for every file so 4th dash symbol is always the divider between first and second part of filename.  The actual date and time varies tho and the text part of the file name also varies.

It is not a requirement for the full date and timestamp to be rewritten in the new filename so in this example the following would be ok as a result.

`CookingDoughnuts-2017-11-09-00.00.00.txt`

Hours, mins and secs can be all 00, but the date needs to be intact.

Comment: When doing any sort of bulk rename/move like this, be sure to use `mv -n` or `mv -i` to avoid files being overwritten if there's a name conflict or naming bug or...

Answer (score 1):

[Parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

```
fname="2017-11-09-23.00.19-CookingDoughnuts.txt"
ext="${fname##*.}"
name="${fname%.*}"
pref="${name#*-*-*-*-}"
suff="${name%-$pref}"
newfname="$pref-$suff.$ext"
echo "$newfname"
```